# Deflate Format: differences between type blocks

Tags: c, deflate

I am currently trying to write a compressor and decompressor with the same purpose as the RFC Deflate specification.

I'm not able to understand the difference between how blocks are composed in the compression with fixed tables and dynamic tables. The file is processed by LZ77 generating `(distance, length) + literal`.

- How do I know the type of block?
- Do I have to compress this data?
- Given that I use a fixed compression and don't have to send the tables, how would the encoder know how to encode data?
- Moreover, do I have to send data before the actual compression executes?

I am confused on the difference between fixed tables and the table we send in the dynamic mode, and how the two blocks use them to encode data.

I'm currently reading Data Compression: *The Complete Reference*. Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to compress, you would pick the smaller of the two. zlib's deflate computes what the size of a fixed block, a dynamic block, and a stored block would be, and emits the smallest of the three.

If you are encoding a fixed block, you encode using the fixed code for literal/lengths and distances. This code is provided in the RFC.

Comment: Hi Mark! I really appreciate your answer, but I have another question. How does actually Deflate computes the size of the two block? He necessarily needs to simulate the two encoding and then evaluate what the best would be? I'm saying stupid things?

Comment: Yes. zlib computes the size of all three: dynamic, static, and stored, and picks the smallest.

Comment: Ok! I still have another doubt...this time it concerns the way the code lengths are compressed. After the sequence of 3 bits cls in the order(16,17,18..) I can create the codes and tree used for the next sequence of codes encoded with code length alphabet. My question is: do I have to encode all the possible symbols code lengths or only the number of codes really used? Because my problem concerns how the decompressor could know to which code lengths  assign the symbols used to create the next codes and tree for the actual data.

Comment: Comments are not a place for questions and answers. You should ask a new question.

Comment: Sure! I will do it.